# Imported tv show metadata is inaccurate, in iTunes

Tags: itunes, mac, metadata

I encoded and imported a tv show myself, to iTunes. I selected all of the episodes, and gave them all a generic date of "2013". It worked, except for two episodes, 4 and 5.

[image: Example]

Instead, these episodes show random dates and do not accept new changes ever after I have saved them. I tried restarting iTunes, restarting my mac, and using subler - all to no avail. Does anyone know how to get these dates to disappear?

I'm running OS X 10.9 on a 2010 macbook air, with iTunes version 11.1.3 (8)

Answer (score 1):

Try reimporting these two episodes. Delete the from library and import them again into the library. Sometimes the library file get messed-up and re-imporing solves the problem.